# Issues with devkit 3.3.2 and eclipse CoreException

Tags: mule, mule-studio, devkit

I am trying to create a connector in **Mule Studio 3.4** using **Devkit 3.3.2.**

The following is a **maven (3.0.2)** command which I used to generate the project structure:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.mule.tools.devkit  
-DarchetypeArtifactId=mule-devkit-archetype-cloud-connector  
-DarchetypeVersion=3.4.0 -DgroupId=org.hello -DartifactId=hello-connector  
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DmuleVersion=3.4.1 
-DmuleConnectorName=Hello  -Dpackage=org.hello 
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases
```

after this, I did:

```
"mvn clean package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false -DskipTests"
```

This gave some errors in Studio that seem related to devkit 3.4.0, therefore decided to change the Mule/Devkit version from **3.4.0 to 3.3.2** in the pom.xml:

```
<mule.version>3.3.2</mule.version>
<mule.devkit.version>3.3.2</mule.devkit.version>
```

The following two errors are shown in Studio:

> "The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException. Fix
>   the build path then try building this
>   project   aria-connector      Unknown Java Problem"

and

> "The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException cannot be resolved.
>   It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files AriaActivator.java  /aria-connector/target/generated-sources/mule/org/mule/tooling/ui/contribution  line
>   1 Java Problem"

My environment is **Mac OS X 10.8.4** (error appears in Windows 7 too), **Mule Studio 3.4.0,** java version **"1.6.0_51".**

Has anybody encountered a similar issue or have an idea how to resolve this please?

Thanks

Comment: hmm, I tried Removinh the Mule runtime reference from my own project and run mvn Eclipse:Eclipse. but no luck removing this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0-v20070426</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your POM.

Comment: I'm getting "The attribute comments is undefined for the annotation type Generated" error in 50 files after this modification. Any Idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Nope. New question please, with more info on your environment.